# Время действия сертификата

Tags: https, ssl, letsencrypt

Пользуюсь сертификатом от LetsEncrypt, подключил скрипт на автопродление, но вот боюсь, что он не продлится автоматически и на всех сайтах однажды появится ошибка безопасности.

В анализе с помощью `sslanalyzer.comodoca.com` поле **Valid From** должно каждый день обновляться (становиться текущей датой) или дата изменится на текущую только когда закончится срок действия сертификата и сработает автопродление?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> боюсь, что он не продлится автоматически

проконтролируйте. если до даты окончания действия сертификата осталось меньше месяца (только в таком случае letsencrypt согласится перевыпустить сертификат), а то (не знаю что), что вы запускаете для запроса нового сертификата, отработало, но сертификат остался прежним — пора разбираться с этим самым тем (не знаю чем).

---

**ремарка**: не имею ни малейшего представления, что это за сайт `sslanalyzer.comodoca.com`, и какую информацию он предоставляет.

но если речь про две даты: когда сертификат стал/станет действующим (*notbefore*), и когда сертификат прекратил/прекратит быть действующим (*notafter*), то они записаны непосредственно в сертификате и, конечно, не меняются.

получаете новый сертификат — у него будут новые даты начала и конца действия.

посмотреть их можно с помощью программы *openssl* примерно так:

```
$ openssl x509 -noout -startdate -enddate -in файл.с.сертификатом 
notBefore=Jun  7 15:26:28 2017 GMT
notAfter=Aug 30 15:11:00 2017 GMT
```

или, скачав сертификат с действующего сервера:

1. http-сервер, порт 443 (https):

   ```
   $ : | openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -startdate -enddate
   notBefore=Jun  7 15:26:28 2017 GMT
   notAfter=Aug 30 15:11:00 2017 GMT
   ```
2. smtp-сервер, порт 25 (smtp, starttls):

   ```
   $ : | openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:25 -starttls smtp 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -startdate -enddate
   notBefore=Jun  7 15:35:24 2017 GMT
   notAfter=Aug 30 15:11:00 2017 GMT
   ```
3. imap-сервер, порт 143 (imap, starttls):

   ```
   $ : | openssl s_client -connect imap.yandex.ru:143 -starttls imap 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -startdate -enddate
   notBefore=Apr 28 17:54:16 2016 GMT
   notAfter=Apr 28 17:54:16 2018 GMT
   ```
4. imap-сервер, порт 993 (imaps)

   ```
   $ : | openssl s_client -connect imap.gmail.com:993 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -startdate -enddate
   notBefore=Jun  7 15:28:03 2017 GMT
   notAfter=Aug 30 15:11:00 2017 GMT
   ```

Comment: Спасибо, не знал, что **letsencrypt согласится перевыпустить сертификат только если до даты окончания его действия осталось меньше месяца**. Тогда за месяц до окончания действия сертификата проверю его.

Comment: @hivokas letsencrypt сам рассылает письма, если сертификат близится к концу

Comment: @etki, письма посылают по адресу, указанному в soa-записи домена?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin по адресу, указанному при генерации сертификата

Comment: @etki, **если** указан. (подтверждение опциональности указания email — [в коде клиента](https://github.com/lukas2511/dehydrated/blob/master/dehydrated#L278), которым я пользуюсь)